# htaccess redirect params from one clean URL to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to redirect everything that comes to 
a.example.com/CODE
to 
b.example.com/index/CODE

What I have is this:
RedirectMatch 301 "^/(.*)?$" "https://b.example.com/index/?"

CODE - will be a random string
The redirect is working, but how can I pass the random string (CODE) to the new link ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
RedirectMatch ^/([^/]+)/?$ http://b.example.com/index/$1
```

"$1" contains the value of 'pathname' matched by Regular expression pattern.